# Visual Studio - autocomplete a symbol from any namespace (alternative to Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way beside Resharper to get autocompletion on symbols that are not currently imported in a file?

Current behavior is that I can get autocompletion on all imported symbols, for example by using first letter of every part of symbol's name.

Visual Studio is aware of namespaces though, as it offers import when you write exact name of non-imported symbol.